# Toggle Remove Div's Based On Browser Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written this script that adds a Div after every 3rd Div in a container based on the window size of the browser.

What I have below works fine **but it only works once!** So it adds the div and removes them but doesn't add them again if the window gets resized again.

How can I do this so it re-adds the divs if they have already been removed?

```
 var addNth = (function () {
    var len, i = 0, className, prevIndexes = [];

    function isNew (el) {
         return el.hasClass(className); // removed unnecessary parenthesis
    }

    return function (selector, html, nth, className ) {
        var els = $( selector );
        className = className || 'test';

        if ( $.inArray(nth, prevIndexes) === -1 ) {
            prevIndexes.push(nth);

            $.each(els, function( index, el ) {
                el = $(el);
                if ( (i % nth) === 0 && i !== 0 ) {
                    if ( ! isNew(el) ) {
                        el.before( html );
                    }
                }
                i++;
            });
            i = 0;
        }
    }

})();
addNth('div.aDiv','<div class="myClass">Some Content</div>',3);
$(window).resize(function(e) {
   var windowWidth = $(this).width(),
      $myClass = $('div.myContainer > div.myClass');

   if (windowWidth > 1024 && windowWidth < 1700) {
    addNth('div.aDiv','<div class="myClass">Some Content</div>',3);
   }
   else {
    $myClass.remove();
   }
});
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vmg35sL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by adding || $.inArray(nth, prevIndexes) === 0 to the if-statment in addNth().

Try my snippet below, and go full pag, and now try to resize the page/window.

or jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dk5tLb19/2/

```js
var addNth = (function () {
    var len, i = 0, className, prevIndexes = [];

    function isNew (el) {
         return el.hasClass(className); // removed unnecessary parenthesis
    }

    return function (selector, html, nth, className ) {
        var els = $( selector );
        className = className || 'test';

        if ( $.inArray(nth, prevIndexes) === -1 || $.inArray(nth, prevIndexes) === 0 ) {
            prevIndexes.push(nth);

            $.each(els, function( index, el ) {
                el = $(el);
                if ( (i % nth) === 0 && i !== 0 ) {
                    if ( ! isNew(el) ) {
                        el.before( html );
                    }
                }
                i++;
            });
            i = 0;
        }
    }
   
})();
   
addNth('div.aDiv','<div class="myClass">Some Content</div>',3);
var divExists = true;
$(window).resize(function(e) {
   var windowWidth = $(this).width(),
      $myClass = $('div.myContainer > div.myClass');
      
   if (windowWidth > 1024 && windowWidth < 1700) {
       if(!divExists) {
     addNth('div.aDiv','<div class="myClass">Some Content</div>',3);
        divExists = true;
       }
   }
   else {
    $myClass.remove();
       divExists = false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myContainer">
 <div class="aDiv">1</div>
 <div class="aDiv">2</div>
 <div class="aDiv">3</div>
 <div class="aDiv">4</div>
 <div class="aDiv">5</div>
 <div class="aDiv">6</div>
 <div class="aDiv">7</div>
 <div class="aDiv">8</div>
 <div class="aDiv">9</div>
 <div class="aDiv">10</div>
 <div class="aDiv">11</div>
 <div class="aDiv">12</div>
 <div class="aDiv">13</div>
 <div class="aDiv">14</div>
 <div class="aDiv">15</div>
</div>
```

Try my snippet below, and go full pag, and now try to resize the page/window.

Comment: This is working but it adds loads of divs in between when you resize, is there anywhere to just add 1 div?

Comment: With this code no. You need to rewrite your function that adds a div. make a check if the div is there and if so, don't add more divs.

Comment: @BoneStarr, I have now edited my code so it works as you want. I this is the answer to your question please mark i as one. Good luck!